# Detecting odd cycle using mod operator and breadth first search algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs

If we want to detect and **odd cycle** if an undirected graph $G=<V,E>$. Suppose we run BFS algorithm from CLRS book as follows,

[image]

**Q**: Now my question is suppose we have the following graphs:

[image]

The figure to the left above:

- $d[v] \bmod{2} == d[u] \bmod{2}$ equal and gives odd cycle.
- $d[v] \bmod{2} == d[a] \bmod{2}$ not equal remainder, so won't give odd cycle.

The figure to the right above:

- $d[x] \bmod{2} == d[u] \bmod{2}$  not equal remainder, so won't give odd cycle.
- $d[x] \bmod{2} == d[v] \bmod{2}$ not equal remainder, so won't give odd cycle.

**Problem**: so the only case to discover odd cycle is when we have the left right graph and when exactly we compare vertex $v$ distance with $u$ distance. What do you think please? If the mod operator works, can you give your interpretation as why this should work in general please if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea, in a nutshell, is that a graph does not contain an odd cycle iff it is 2-colorable (also known as bipartite).

Your algorithm attempts to find a 2-coloring of the graph. In each connected component, the coloring is unique once we fix the color of one of the vertices, since all neighbors of a white vertex are black and vice versa. The algorithm uses this coloring strategy, and verifies that it results in no monochromatic edges.

Comment: Thank you very much. The mod operator above operates on $d[vertex]=distance$, so it assumes that there is an odd if the mod of both vertices are equal, then we have an odd cycle. So I was trying to ask if this will work for general case. So in case of an odd and 2-colorable  please, how the odd cycle above would be a 2-colorable  and the even cycle to right not please? Can you just give an example please?

Comment: You can try out a sample graph yourself. Just trace the execution of the algorithm.